Flutter web issue (Design is stretching)
The design is good in mobile app, but the width changes in the web mode.
so is there any other specific code for the web or i have to change the main code.
How to deal with that,
video
see the video to get the question what im trying to say

The web version looks ok to me. Maybe you could clarify in your post what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When developing flutter app/website, you need to check the design for each platform throughout the development process.
In your video, for example, you can use a Wrap, and set a maxWidth and maxHeight for the Cards.
Flutter also provides a widget called LayoutBuilder to manage the size of the parent widget.
There are some useful packages in this case:

Check the design without changing platforms: device_preview
For an easy-to-use responsive solution, there's responsive_framework

